# Deleting records from two seperate entity in core data

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7

What I Know

1: During a transaction or a view I am able to delete  records from a single entity(table) --Success :)

What I am trying to do

- Entity(table) 1  :  Inventory (Name type Purchase date ........
  Category name )
- Entity(table) 2  :  Category (Category name, Category Type)

In the code  for a category view When I delete a category I want the corresponding Inventory Item to be deleted ;

I know I can set some relationship for this delete , but I was unable to find a good link or a example which does that , I am unable to apply that rule

Here's my code

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {

 PIMCategoryListCellTableViewCell *cell = (PIMCategoryListCellTableViewCell*) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // [self.tblView beginUpdates];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    //Records from Category entity(table) deleted  -- Success So far 
    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }


   // Use the fetch result controller to get the corresponding item of same category 
    self.fetchedResultsControllerCategory = nil;
        [self fetchedResultsControllerItem:cell.categoryName.text];
        NSUInteger count = [self.fetchedResultsControllerCategory.fetchedObjects count];
        //this way I know if any item are present for the category 
         if (count> 0)
        {

      NSManagedObjectContext  *contextN = [self.fetchedResultsControllerCategory managedObjectContext];


            NSIndexPath *i;

            for ( i.row =0 ; i==1;i++ )
            {

           [contextN deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsControllerCategory  ob ];

            }

            //     @property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
       //  [contextN deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsControllerCategory ob ];



       //[contextN reset]
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![contextN save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();

            // [self.tblView endUpdates];
        }

        }}
```

Now I have tried to change the context but still  unable to delete the second entity(table) records

Any suggestion , ; Let me know if you need more explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up the relationship in the core data editor.

Get rid of the 'category name' attribute from Inventory, and instead create a relationship to Category. (And an inverse relationship from Category to Inventory)

Then you can set the delete rule on the category relationship to "Cascade" which will then delete any related Inventory, as soon as you delete a category.[image: screenshot of relationship in core data editor]

Comment: Now I want to delete the records when user deletes the certain Type of category , can we do a conditional delete rule in the releationship  ??

Answer (score 0):

Okay , lets get things right , you have two entities , Inventories and Categories.

Each category has many inventories ,and if a user deletes a category all the inventories should automatically get deleted.

Its fairly simple to do this and it can be done in the Model editor of XCODE.

After creating the two entities , just drag a relationship from one entity to the other.
double click where it says , newRelationship and give your relationship names.
Select the relationship on categories and click on the Model Editor in the top left corner and change the TYPE to  MANY. Also change the Delete Rule to - CASCADE.
Check out my attached image to make sense of it all. 
Then you could just user your conventional Managed Object Context Methods to delete your categories and it should automatically delete the inventories associated with that category. [image]

Comment: Thanx will Try , One question How the Coredata understand which record to delete Please find the structure  
 \n Category ( Category Name , Category Type)
         ( Electronic    , Type)
         ( Furniture     , Type)
         ( Home          , Location)
         ( Office        , Location)

Comment: Inventory ( Name , Price ,Date,........., Category Type , Category Location , Category Status ) 
Inventory ( Bed, 256 ,02/02/2014,........., Furniture, Home , New ) 
Inventory ( TV, 256 ,04/02/2013,........., Electronic, Home , old ) 
 Now I want to delete the records when user deletes the Type category and not when other category are deleted  , can we do a conditional delete rule in the releationship ??

Comment: Im not aware if conditional delete exists , if you need conditional delete you could manage the deleting of inventory objects when a category gets deleted. Set your delete rule to NO ACTION but maintain a one-to-many relationship from categories to inventories.And when you find that the inventories need to be deleted for a category you could get an NSSet of all the inventory Managed objects associated with that category and manually call delete.